# What expectations should I have of large (> 2 GB) file support in common mesh workflow tools?

Tags: mesh

I have an experimental workflow that involves very finely subdivided meshes, above the 2 GB limit where signed 32-bit integers stop working, which often causes problems for various tools. I would need my users to be able to handle such mesh files. How big a problem will this be? Do commonplace mesh editing and DCC tools (commercial and free) have trouble with files with more than 2 GB size, or more than 2^31 vertices? I'd imagine at least movie industry tools would be fine with this kind of size, because they store a lot of intermediate files that may have been generated from displacement maps or by marching-cubes on volumes.

I'm not interested in problems caused by 32-bit OSes or 32-bit installs of tools: my product only supports 64-bit, so it's OK for me to just tell people to use the 64-bit versions of other tools if that's sufficient. But even with this advice, is my large-file-based workflow a non-starter (because users will keep having problems), is it a manageable problem, or is it not a problem at all?